# Create ggplot with two labels/legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

How can I make a ggplot that has two labels/legends?

Example data dput():

`structure(list(Percentage = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 0, 25, 50, 
75, 100), Data = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2"), accuracy_G = c(18.35, 
54.53, 68.48, 88.65, 99.96, 18.35, 76.08, 81.63, 88.03, 99.96
), accuracy_1 = c(52.751572327044, 61.5566037735849, 65.8411949685535, 
73.8011006289308, 80.6112421383648, 52.751572327044, 64.7209119496855, 
67.3054245283019, 70.5090408805032, 80.6112421383648), accuracy_2 = c(52.8498427672956, 
61.1930031446541, 66.0966981132076, 73.8404088050314, 80.3360849056604, 
52.8498427672956, 64.5538522012579, 67.1678459119497, 70.9217767295598, 
80.3360849056604)), .Names = c("Percentage", "Data", "accuracy_G", 
"accuracy_1", "accuracy_2"), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 
12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L), class = "data.frame")`

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
data.melt <- melt(data, id.vars=c("Percentage","Data")) #For plotting with ggplot
```

Now I can plot part of the figure by subsetting:

```
data.melt_sub <- subset(data.melt,Data == "group1")
ggplot( data.melt_sub ,aes(x = Percentage,y = value,colour=variable)) + geom_line()
```

However, I would like to have two labels on the right, one for 'group1' and one for 'group2' (each creating 3 lines). For the colours of the lines i would like to use the palette = "Paired", from the brewer. These could be called by hand with, but including something like scale_fill_brewer(pallete = "Paired") would be better:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
colours <- brewer.pal(12,"Paired")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your full melted data frame and then for `color=` inside `aes()` provide interaction between Data and variable. Then with `scale_color_manual()` change line colors and labels inside the legend.

```
ggplot( data.melt ,aes(x = Percentage,y = value,colour=interaction(Data,variable))) + 
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=brewer.pal(6,"Paired"),
                                   labels=rep(c("Group1","Group2"),times=3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, tried things with group etc, but they didn't work. This works perfectly.